# Validation list with multiple criterias

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I sort out my problem but I am wondering if an easier way doing it doesn't exist.

With the function onEdit(), I am creating from a first validation list, a second validation list in the next cell.
So, the code below is just for information.

```
var validationRange = data.getRange(3, myIndex, data.getLastRow());
var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
```

In this validation list, I need to select a name, taking into account two additionnal criterias :

| Name | Times | LastWeek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patrick | 2 | W22 |
| Rachel | 5 | W15 |
| Claire | 3 | W14 |
| Olivier | 4 | W16 |
| Hélene | 2 | W20 |

It means that "Patrick" attended "2" times and last time was in week "W22".
I need to take into account these two criterias to select one of the attendee

I.E. : I try to let each person participate the same number of times but not every week (the oldest first)

So, I created a validation list with a "sorted key" that allows me to first see the person who has attended less and for longer.

| Key Sorted |
| --- |
| #02W20#Hélene |
| #02W22#Patrick |
| #03W14#Claire |
| #04W16#Olivier |
| #05W15#Rachel |

This validation list is used 3, 5, 7 times in the same sheet because person can do different activities. Then, when all person are selected another script removes the values between # to keep only the name in the final sheet.

So, the question is :
could we create a validation list with multiple columns, the selected value being only the value of the first column.

I guess many users would enjoy it when we glance at questions about multiple criteras selection lists.

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is to create a Dropdown with the names in the sorted order, not the sheet column order?

Comment: I need to select a NAME but I need to know the number of time (NN) they attended and the last week (Wxx) they did attend. So, I build the key #NNWxxNAME to sort out my data by NN, then xx, then NAME. Then I can make the choice for selecting the NAME I want to display. If I could dispay three columns at once in a validation list, selected value being the first column,  it would be great.

Comment: You want to display a table?

Comment: Somehow, I need to see the 3 information (NN, Sxx, NAME) at the same time to decide which name I will select in the cell.

Comment: Coud we display at the same time a validation list and a table with the additional informations ? i.e. : in the validation list, I would have the names and in the table, the "Names", "Times" and "LastWeek" sorted by  increasing values of "Times" and "LastWeek"